# Windows 10 не работает кнопка Пуск и не работает проводник

Tags: windows, windows-10

На 2 компьютерах, где установлена Windows 10 есть проблемы:

1. На 1 компьютере не работает проводник.
2. На обоих компьютерах не работают кнопка Пуск.

На обоих компьютерах включена встроенная учетка администратора.
Под учеткой пользователя с админскими правами не работают на обоих компьютерах кнопка Пуск.

Comment: а безопасный режим?

Comment: На клавах нигде кнопки не зажаты? В USB не включены сгоревшие устройства? Хоть какие-то действия можно проводить?

Comment: С компом все нормально..

Answer (score 1):

1 способ - перезапустить explorer.exe. Открываем диспетчер задач `Ctrl+Shift+Esc`, внизу жмем `Подробнее`, находим `Проводник`. Правой кнопкой по нему и выбираем `Перезапустить`

2 способ - правим реестр. `Win+R`, вводим `regedit`. Заходим в раздел `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`. Смотрим справа, есть ли параметр `EnableXAMLStartMenu`, если есть - двойной клик и устанавливаем значение 0. Если нет - создаем `DWORD` и устанавливаем значение 0

Comment: Попробывал оба способа, не работает ни один(((

Answer (score -2):

Причин может быть несколько, но которая из них стала причиной такого поведения можно лишь догадываться.

Например, в системе активирован AppLocker, точнее "Правила исполняемых файлов" в последнем, тогда чтобы вновь заработали "Пуск" и проводник следует активировать "Правила упакованных приложений" и все встанет на свои места. Если в вашей редакции Windows AppLocker не поддерживается,

во-первых, стоит проверить групповые политики (но опять-таки, если это не Home),

во-вторых, воспользоваться утилитой [autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns), дабы удостовериться что проводник (то бишь explorer.exe) присутствует среди автоматически загружаемых компонентов,

в-третьих, если в системе активирован режим контрольных точек, стоит попробовать откатиться на одну из ранних из них,

в-четвертых, попробовать загрузиться в безопасном режиме,

в-пятых, попытаться загрузиться с установочно(й\го) флэшки\диска и восстановить систему с не(е\го). Также можно посоветовать попробовать обратиться за помощью к утилите sfc (параметр /scannow).

Повторюсь, сложно сказать в чем именно причина, не имея на руках развернутой информации.